# Git RPC failed http 100% curl 22 unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, github-pages

Estoy tratando de hacer el segundo commit de un repositorio.
El primero fue el readme.
No tengo idea como solucionar este error.
Vi muchos ejemplos y soluciones a problemas similares, pero no puedo solucionarlo.
Alguna ayuda?

```
$ git push
```

`Enumerating objects: 6345, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6345/6345), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6087/6087), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (6344/6344), 7.04 GiB | 8.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 6344 (delta 3054), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás pasando a través de un proxy para llegar al repositorio remoto?